# Lint is giving error if I use java.lang.Iterable#forEach in android code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lint, android-lint

In my android code (Kotlin) I am using forEach method of java iterable.

```
mandatoryViews.forEach { view ->
   // my code here
}
```

Below is my sdk config in build.gradle (app):

```
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Now my code builds fine. I also tried to run it on API 23 pixel device and everything is working fine.

But after I run `gradlew lint` to see lint errors, it fails and report gives me this error:
`Call requires API level 24 (current min is 23): java.lang.Iterable#forEach`

[image: lint error]

Not able to figure why does lint think it will not work on API 23 whereas on API 23 device my code is running fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185418482) is fixed in lint supplied with Android Gradle plugin 4.2, with 4.2.1 being the latest stable release right now.

Update your project-level build.gradle to have

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
```

in its `buildscript.dependencies` block.

Comment: Just a note: that issue link requires a Google login.

Comment: This issue link indicates this is not resolved as of AGP 7.0.2 even.
  
However, worth noting that replacing `mandatoryViews.forEach` with `mandatoryViews.iterator().forEach` does fix the issue. 
  

The root cause is a confusion between the Kotlin `Iterable.forEach` extension function and the Java8 `forEach` function.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue again even with AGP 7.0.4, the solution seems to be more having 'matching' kotlin and AGP versions rather than about a specific version of AGP being the solution.

Comment: I can confirm @Trevor idea.

Comment: @Trevor it's true in my case.
Increasing AGP to 7.4.2 and Gradle to 7.5.1 make it work for Kotlin version 1.8.21.
 AGP 7.3.1 and Gradle 7.4 with for Kotlin version 1.8.21. gave error mentioned here

Comment: same issue on agp 8.0.0