# Error: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.util.Map#forEach [NewApi]

Tags: java, android, kotlin, collections, kotlin-extension

I have two **enum** class **EventKey** and **EventProperty**

```
enum class EventKey(val firebaseKey: String? = null) {
       SIGNIN(firebaseKey = "singin"),
       .....
}

enum class EventProperty(val property: String) {
    TYPE1("type1"),
    ....
}
```

I am getting error on this

```
fun event(eventKey: EventKey, properties: Map<EventProperty, Any>) {
        eventKey.firebaseKey?.let { key ->
            properties?.forEach { entry ->
                eventData.put(entry.key.property, entry.value)
            }
        }
}
```

I tried this [Kotlin Extension Functions suddenly require api level 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751469/kotlin-extension-functions-suddenly-require-api-level-24/44752239), [Lint considers Kotlin MutableMap.forEach() as java.util.Map.forEach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437358/lint-considers-kotlin-mutablemap-foreach-as-java-util-map-foreach)
 and change the code

```
properties?.forEach { (entry) ->
     eventData.put(entry.property, entry)
}
```

or

```
properties?.forEach { (entry,value) ->
     eventData.put(entry.property, value)
 }
```

It giving the same error on lint checking, also what i am doing in code after changing the stack overflow answer.

Using Kotlin **1.5.20**

Comment: Can you please check the package of Map

Comment: @mightyWOZ ```package kotlin.collections```

Comment: Have you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68046641)?

Answer (score 1):

I run into this by bump Kotlin from `1.7.22` to `1.8.0`

```
Error: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 21): java.lang.Iterable#forEach [NewApi]
            allArrived(clientHandle).forEach {
                                     ~~~~~~~
```

#### My solution

I bumped from

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1` to

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.0` and now it's working for me